# How to "attach" data to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using JS, I'm adding buttons to a div by looping over a JSON list. When a button is pressed, a request needs to be made. The request is different for each button.

```js
// example json object for button
obj = {
    "name": "Test1",
    "id": 15,
    "link": "http://example.com"
};

// js to make button
table = document.getElementById('div-list');

button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    data = {
        'id': obj.id
    }
    fetch(obj.link, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
});

table.appendChild(button);
```

You can see the `obj.id` and `obj.link`. That is where the info from the json object needs to go. However, this doesn't work because the function is run when clicked, so the variable `obj` won't exist anymore. So I basically need to store the JSON in the `button` element so that when the button is clicked, it can get it's info.

Is there some way to allow that button-click-function access to "it's data" in order for it to determine where to send it's request to?

Comment: If you want to store data on an element you create, you can use the `data` attribute, for example `<button data-myid="3"></button>`. After clicking the button you can get that data back with `event.target.dataset.myid`.

Comment: @Kokodoko can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data on an element you create, you can use the data attribute, for example

```
<button data-myid="3"></button>
```

After clicking the button you can get that data back with

```
event.target.dataset.myid
```